# Spark streaming from Heroku postgresql using kafka as add-on

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, pyspark, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to use pyspark in databricks to stream from Heroku postgres database using kafka as an add-on. I have the code as such below but it runs continuously without returning anything and no errors. I tried adding trigger to code but do not know what import to use as I did not find its package online.
`.trigger(continuous="1 second")`

q.explain and q.status only gives the message

> No physical plan. Waiting
> for data. {'message': 'Initializing sources', 'isDataAvailable':
> False, 'isTriggerActive': False}

I used kafka-python and was able to read the streams, but using pyspark returns nothing. pyspark code I am using is

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("TablesStream") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers) \
  .option("subscribe", topic) \
.option("kafka.group.id", topic) \
.option("includeHeaders", "true") \
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
.option("kafka.ssl.protocol", "SSL") \
.option("kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols", "SSL") \
.option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "") \
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "/databricks/ca.pem" ) \
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore", "ca.pem" ) \
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PEM" ) \
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", "/databricks/cert.pem" ) \
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore", "cert.pem" ) \
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.key", "key.pem" ) \
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.type", "PEM" ) \
  .load()

q=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
.outputMode("append") \
    .start()

q.explain()
print(q.status)
print(q.lastProgress)

q.awaitTermination()
```

Please what am I not doing right here and is the SSL files options stated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing:

```
.option("kafka.security.protocol","SSL")
```

Comment: I tried that and it was giving me SSL handshake error, so I changed it to .option("kafka.ssl.protocol", "SSL"). What would cause it not to read/display the stream messages?